# Google Sign on OAuth using Firebase Auth on iOS/Cordova loads forever

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

We are using Firebase Auth on a Cordova app, and using it to handle Google sign in. On web, android, and even on iOS Safari, it works just fine. On our cordova iOS app though, logging in the first time will work fine if it makes you type in your email and password, but, if you go to log in and you get the "Choose an Account" screen on google to pick what email to sign in with, it ends up just loading forever when you pick the account.

Looking at the logs of what is happening, it is just calling https://accounts.google.com/_/signin/oauth and then nothing happens after that. The firebase handler URL is never called. There are no error messages in the console, nor do any of the Google requests returning errors in their responses.

We are using firebase hosting, for our web version, and for the firebase 'authDomain' (which is the same domain we are using for web).

iOS was previously working fine for us, but I'm not sure if it was iOS 16 that started the issue, or changes we made, or changes on Google's end.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

We figured out the issue, it appears a cordova plugin we were using that had gotten upgraded had a bug in the new version that stopped custom url schemes from working. We upgraded again to a version that had the bug fixed and the issue stopped.